# What is the white colored connector circled in red in the picture of a laptop motherboard called?

Tags: electrical-engineering, computer-hardware

[image: ASUS S550CM Back Panel]

This is a picture of the back of my laptop (An [ASUS S550CM](https://www.asus.com/Laptops/ASUS_VivoBook_S550CM/specifications/)) with a motherboard/HDD/RAM access panel removed.

The white connector connects the motherboard with the laptops back panel which in turns has contact with the battery. It is either the power cable for the motherboard or for the speakers which are battery-integrated.

The cable has not been disconnected in 5 years. I want to remove the back panel, clean the heatsink and fans of accumulated dust but am unable to remove the back panel since I am unable to disconnect this wire. My questions

1. I tried using tweezers to disconnect this wire but was not sure as to how much pressure to apply. Since the connector has not been removed in 5 years, is there anything I can apply or spray to loosen it up and smoothly disconnect without risking damage to the motherboard ?
2. What does this connector do - is it a power cable for the motherboard or for the speakers or something else entirely?
3. What is the name of this sort of connector? (a general commercial name which will let me locate this on eBay if I happen to break it)
4. What is the name for the connecting wire? Are these wires easily available in the market? (I live in Sydney, Australia)

Comment: I guess it three pin CPU fan connector is, you should be able to remove it easily, if you are trying too hard then i think you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a Molex or AMP 4-pin power connector. Note the AMP and Molex versions are similar, but not interchangeable. See  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molex_connector.

AMP connectors have one or two tabs which click into place and "lock" the parts together when you connect them. You need to bend the tab(s) to release them while you are pulling on the plug to remove it. The two "ears" on the ends of the connector in your picture may be these locking tabs.

This video isn't very clear, but at about 1:30 it looks like the guy is using a small screwdriver to bend back the end tabs at the same time as pulling on the plug. Once the plug has started to move, the tab will be "unlocked" and you can then fully remove the plug without bothering about the tabs.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qhRuU7EAA_E

These connectors can be a tight fit - even when you release the locking tabs, you may still need quite a bit of force to unplug it. Try to pull on the shell of the connector itself, not on the wires!

Answer (score 1):

> 3) What is the name of this sort of connector?
>   (a general commercial name which will let me locate this on eBay if I
>   happen to break it)

I'll hazard a guess that this is [Molex PicoBlade](http://www.molex.com/molex/products/family?key=picoblade&channel=products&chanName=family&pageTitle=Introduction).
If that's the case, then the pitch should be 1.25mm.

Please measure the pitch (center-to-center distance between the pins) and update your question with that information.

Related threads on the Electrical Engineering stack.  [Surface-mount PicoBlade header](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/164791/7036) like yours.  [Throughole header](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/245257/7036), same connector family.
(Be advised, however, that repair and identification questions are frowned upon on the Electrical Engineering stack.  Please don't misconstrue these references as an invitation to post repair and identification questions to the Electrical Engineering stack.)